# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column *name* does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

So, my Django app was working just fine when I used the default sqllite database. I then switched to postgres database for heroku deployment but now nothing works.

My model looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    temperature = models.IntegerField()
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

now nothing loads and I get the errors like:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column weather_post.name does not exist

LINE 1: ... AS "temperature__max" FROM "weather_post" WHERE ("weather_p...

Comment: did you execute `manage.py make migrations` `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: yes, they go through without complaining but when I run the app the error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is because of DB models is not migrated in heroku server. Already written use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514008/unable-to-make-rds-queries-on-heroku/48514232#48514232)

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer. Thank you, this was indeed the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that what you have done is to create or modify the name of a variable in the "models.py" file. The problem arises after making this modification and trying to run "python manage.py makemigrations" or "test" code, or even trying "runserver" etc.

The problem is that you are calling the class from another file, the whole class, the model. So when querying from another file to models.py, it calls all the variables contained in the class, and this in turn makes the query in the database. And obviously, it doesn't find the associated column.

There are two solutions.

The first is to manually create the columns in the databases. In many cases the most practical.

Another is to comment out ALL the lines of code that call the model (the class inside models.py and some/all variables), rerun "python manage.py makemigrations". And terminate the whole process (migrate, sqlmigrate...). Then uncomment ALL the lines again.

There are more parallel solutions, but they are all based on the same thing, that a file is calling a class inside models.py, and this is calling the database, and it doesn't find the column associated. It shouldn't happen, but it can happen (as in my case), that you are working with Django in an unorthodox way, and queries are being executed from a .py to the database in a particular/preferent way.