# unable to make RDS queries on heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, rds

I can access my RDS postresql database on a local machine no problem.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'xxxxxxx',
    'USER': 'XXXXXXXX',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXX',
    'HOST': 'XXXXXXrds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

I pushed this to Heroku and I get a ProgrammingError at /saferdb/query/

In manage.py shell on heroku I tried to access the database:

```
>>> from saferdb.models import Question
>>> q = Question.objects.all()
>>> q.count()
```

got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "saferdb_question" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "saferdb_question"
                                          ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 387, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 491, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 476, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1063, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "saferdb_question" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "saferdb_question"
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, also for a Django on Heroku app. I used the [heroku-django-template](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template%20heroku-django-template) to create my app. In settings.py, the `default` database is [overwritten](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template/blob/master/project_name/settings.py#L112) by the environment variable `DATABASE_URL`.

You can either disable that in the settings.py or set the env var to the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

The Error is because of table doesn't exists in Database, that means you need to migrate the database models. For Further reference read django migrations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/)

Database migrations in heroku is done by this way, specify the line in Procfile file.

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn col.wsgi --log-file -
```

So Whenever you deploy a new code, heroku will automatically migrate the DB models. For further reference, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410107/running-manage-py-migrate-during-heroku-deployment).
let me know if this works.

Comment: I did what you said, and now the programming error is gone. but I am still not getting any data from RDS. Did I set it up incorrectly?

Comment: Check whether table is created.

Comment: I think they are created I ran heroku manage.py shell and I was able to run an sql command but there are no entries.

Comment: If no entries is there what you will get. Try to insert some data and let me know.

Comment: I can't just insert some data I need to access data hosted in Amazon RDS

Comment: Can you clarify what you want exactly?

Comment: I postgresql database runing on Amazon RDS I need to query data from it using my heroku app.

Comment: When you are querying what you are getting empty list or error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164142/discussion-between-sakthi-selvam-and-lev).